# Set OpenJDK JVM Crash Dump Location

Tags: java, java-8, jvm

I'm using OpenJDK 8 and I'm trying to figure out a way to set the JVM binary dump location.
This is the output of my  java -version:
openjdk version "1.8.0_232"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 1.8.0_232-b09)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 25.232-b09, mixed mode)

When a crash occurs in native code, the JVM generates 2 files in the current directory -
text file - relatively small file with call stacks
binary mdmp file - large dump file

I was able to set the location of the text file using this flag -
-XX:ErrorFile

however any attempt to set the location of the binary file failed
I tries with - -XX:HeapDumpPath
but it didn't work. The JVM accepted this flag but didn't write the dump in the right location.

Comment: Did you check `xx:HeapDumpPath` option?
https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/troubleshoot/command-line-options1.html#GUID-DE9FAAAF-DCD4-4974-A86F-C6B8907CCE9A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have mentioned "mdmp", I assume you are on Windows.

Currently it's not possible to change the default location of JVM minidumps on Windows. It is [hard-coded](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/54f222098a52/src/os/windows/vm/os_windows.cpp#l1038) to be the current process directory. So, the workaround is to start Java from a different directory.

The issue [JDK-8021940](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8021940) and the corresponding [email thread](https://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/hotspot-runtime-dev/2013-July/008426.html) are exactly about this problem. Unforunately, the issue has been closed as "Won't Fix", but you may try to revive the question on the [mailing list](https://mail.openjdk.java.net/mailman/listinfo/hotspot-runtime-dev).